# Is it possible to use a variable that was declared in a function that is after the variable?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the user's input from the `Entry` widget. I set the variable `turtle_bet` 's value to the user's string input. I set the variable `bet_amount`'s value to the user's integer input. However, I want to implement these two variables to a function that is before the `enter_input` function. I tried using the keyword global but it doesn't appear to work. Is there any way to do this?

```py
from tkinter import *

def enter_input():
    global turtle_bet
    global bet_amount

    turtle_bet = user_turtle_bet.get()
    bet_amount = user_bet_amount.get()





## Tkinter Entry Setup
tk = Tk()

user_turtle_bet = StringVar()
user_bet_amount = IntVar()

user_turtle_label = Label(tk, text="Turtle Bet", font=('Times', 13, 'bold'))
user_turtle_entry = Entry(tk, textvariable=user_turtle_bet, font=('Times', 13, 'normal'))

user_amount_label = Label(tk, text="Bet Amount", font=('Times', 13, 'bold'))
user_amount_entry = Entry(tk, textvariable=user_bet_amount, font=('Times', 13, 'normal'))

enter_button = Button(tk, text="ENTER", command=enter_input)

user_turtle_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
user_turtle_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
user_amount_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
user_amount_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
enter_button.grid(row=2, column=1)



tk.mainloop()
```

What I am trying to add before the `def enter_input()` function:

```py
def random_function():
    bet_amount += 67
```

Comment: What do you mean by "before"? Do you mean "appearing first in the source code?" "being called previously"? Something else?

Comment: If you are going to try to change a `global` variable, you need the `global <variable>` again. Add `global bet_amount` to the start of `random_function`

Comment: do you have `turtle_bet` and `bet_amount` declared in the global scope?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'm saying that I want to utilize the variables turtle_bet and bet_amount in a function that will be placed before the enter_input() function

Comment: @tromgy Yea pretty sure I do.

Comment: @TheLizzard I'll try that

Comment: The order isn't the issue. The issue is that you a) need to have a global variable to refer to; b) need to make sure you understand how the `global` statement actually works.

Comment: Separately: you should try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for problems like this. It should be pretty clear to you that the problem isn't caused by using `tkinter`, right? So try to create code that just shows the problem, without the tkinter setup stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best Option is to define the variable beforehand and set it for example to `None` or since you alway increase the number, to `0`:

```
bet_amount = 0
```

---

Alternatively:

You can check if the variable already exists, and handle it differently:

```
def random_function():
    global bet_amount
    if 'bet_amount' in globals():
        bet_amount += 67
    else:
        bet_amount = 67
```

But solution 1 which explicitly defined the variable seems cleaner to me.

Comment: You still need the `global bet_amount` at the start of that function.

Comment: I think it is best that you avoid using `globals` and make use of `None`.

Comment: @CoolCloud added that as well, I thought that was the most obvious solution which is why i skipped it, but you are ofc right. Thanks for the comment.